# InAppSettingsKit pop the UINavigationController automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, inappsettingskit

Is it possible with IASK to have a PSMultiValueSpecifier automatically pop the stack when the user makes their selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, currently. The current behavior is identical to the system settings app. I can see the usefulness of this and it wouldn't be hard to integrate this, possibly with a custom `IASKPopOnSelect` attribute in the plist that enables this. Feel free to contribute, we're gladly accepting pull requests ;-)

Comment: can you point me in the right direction as far as how it could be integrated?

Comment: check `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController`: `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. There you wanna pop yourself from the navigation stack. To add a `IASKPopOnSelect` specifier, create a getter in `IASKSpecifier` and query `_currentSpecifier` in your `IASKSpecifierValuesViewController`.

Comment: Thanks Ortwin. one last thing, could you tell me how i can traverse back to the IASKAppSettingsDelegate from that method in IASKSpecifierValuesViewController to pop the view? i assume that i want to call [super popViewControllerAnimated:YES] on the IASKAppSettingsDelegate but i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Why don't you do a `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`?